# Python code to remove duplicates in a 2D list

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list [[1,0], [14,12], [13,6], [1,0], [12,8], [13,6]]
I want the output as [[1,0], [14,12], [13,6], [12,8]]

Please help me out with a solution code in python.

Comment: On a related note, searching "python 2d list remove duplicates" on Google pulls up plenty of relevant results. That should be the first port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can put distinct values into a new list by iterating through the old list and checking the new one in a for loop. Like this:

```
lst = [[1,0], [14,12], [13,6], [1,0], [12,8], [13,6]]
newlist = []

for i in lst:
    if i in newlist:
        continue
    else:
        newlist.append(i)

print(newlist)
```